# Factory concrete return type based on generic

Tags: c#, generics, factory

I'm trying to implement a factory that returns a class based on what generic it gets called with.

I currently have it working like this:

```
public static TRepository GetInstance<T, TRepository>()
    where TRepository : IRepository<T>, new()
{
    return new TRepository();
}
```

Calling it like this:

```
InvoiceRepository repo = RepositoryFactory.GetInstance<Invoice, InvoiceRepository>();
```

This works, but I'd rather not have to declare the return type. I'd like to call it like this:

```
InvoiceRepository repo = RepositoryFactory.GetInstance<Invoice>();
```

It's not really important, but it's just bothering me and I'm curious if there are any obvious solutions.

Comment: Which type should the factory construct? Should it search the loaded assemblies for types that implement the `IRepository<T>` interface?

Comment: Not sure if that's a rhetorical question, but yeah it should return the implementation of IRepository<T>, as there is only one of each. e: I'm still a student and it's very possible I'm a little oblivious about something that may be obvious to others.

Comment: You can create a private dictionary (`Dictionary<Type,Type>`) in the factory that maps between different `T`s and their corresponding repository types. Then, when you are asked to construct the repository, you can use the dictionary to get the type of the repository and then use reflection to construct the repository type.

Comment: @YacoubMassad I'll give this a shot tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{

}

public static class RepositoryFactory
{
    public static IRepository<T> GetInstance<T>()
                where T : new()
    {
        return new Repository<T>();
    }
}
```

Then, call it like this:

```
var repo = RepositoryFactory.GetInstance<Invoice>();
```

Comment: My implementations don't use generics, and I don't see how I'd implement your suggestion. My impl is like this: `public class InvoiceRepository : IRepository<Invoice> { //.. }`. I don't know if that helps though.